# React - assigning ref via loop to image array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, loops

I am still very new to this and probably completely overthinking/overcomplicating things.

I have an array of images which display as expected. As part of the mapping process, I create a new ref for each image, so that I can tap into the 'current' attribute to retrieve height and width, based on which I have a ternary operator to apply some styling. I doubt this is the only or best method to achieve this and I am open to suggestions...

Now to the problem. If I have one image and one ref, the above process works great, however, once I introduce more images and attempt to get 'current' it fails. But I can console log my ref array and I get everything back including the dimensions of the image.

The problem is staring me in the face but I simply cannot figure out what the problem is. It may simply be that I have misunderstood how references and current work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My code as follows:

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect, createRef } from "react";
import Images from "../images";

const IllustrationList = () => {
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // populate with Images from Images Array
    setImages(Images);
  }, []);

  // ref array
  const imageRefs = [];
  const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState({ width: 0, height: 0 });
  useEffect(() => {
    if (imageRefs.current) {
      setDimensions({
        width: imageRefs.current.naturalWidth,
        height: imageRefs.current.naturalHeight,
      });
    }
  });
  return (
    <div className="illustration-gallery">
      <ul className="cropped-images pl-0">
        {images.map((image, i) => {
          const newRef = createRef();
          imageRefs.push(newRef);
          return (
            <li className="li-illustration" key={i}>
              <a href={image.image} data-lightbox="mygallery">
                <img
                  src={image.image}
                  alt="illustrations"
                  ref={newRef}
                  className={
                    dimensions.width > dimensions.height ? "imageSize" : ""
                  }
                />
              </a>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default IllustrationList;
```

Comment: `imageRefs` is just an array (of refs) so it itself won't have a `current` property. Since `imageRefs` is defined in the function body it is also redeclared each render cycle. Which image's dimensions do you want to access/store in local state? Or do you want `dimensions` to be an array of dimensions? Additionally, the render function should be pure, i.e. you shouldn't be creating refs there when mapping image elements.

Comment: Hey Drew, thanks for your comment. I need the dimensions for all images and then apply styling based on that. Perhaps there is another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve my problem.

I think I was completely overthinking the problem and came up with a much simpler solution. I don't know if this is the best way to achieve this, but it does what I want/need it to.

```
  useEffect(() => {
let landScape = document.querySelectorAll("img");
landScape.forEach(() => {
  for (var i = 0; i < Images.length; i++) {
    if (landScape[i].naturalWidth > landScape[i].naturalHeight) {
      landScape[i].className = "landscape";
    }
  }
});
```